# Relations between LR coefficients and cores and quotients of partitions

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, partitions

I have a formula for certain coefficients in terms of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients and $p$-cores and $p$-quotients of partitions ($p$ is a prime). I would like to obtain some positivity conditions from this formula.

I am looking for results that relate Littlewood-Richardson coefficients with cores and quotients of a partition. Some examples of the type of result include:

1. Given partition $\lambda, \mu_1,\mu_2$ with $c^{\lambda}_{\mu_1,\mu_2}>0$, what can be said about the p-cores and p-quotients of $\mu_1,\mu_2$?
2. Given a partition $\lambda$ with $p$-quotient $(\nu_0,\dotsc,\nu_{p-1})$, for what partitions $\nu$ is $c^{\nu}_{\nu_0,\dotsc,\nu_{p-1}}$ nonzero?

In general I would like any references that connect both these concepts. I apologise if this is a vague request.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The closest I can think of is the Littlewood map, and the modular hook-formula: http://symmetricfunctions.com/borderStripTableaux.htm#littlewoodMap
I have not seen LR-coefficients from this perspective

Comment: 1. Obviously, the size of the $p$-core of $\lambda$ is congruent modulo $p$ to the sum of the sizes of the $p$-cores of $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. I would be somewhat surprised if anything other than this would hold for the $p$-cores alone. ...

Comment: ... [Some Sage code to experiment with $p = 2$.](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUDtPwzAQ3v0rTmKxIVTQgQHoykzVsQlVmjrUanxO_WhVEP-du7gURepNyfc83-JkYQaLk7U6etO8JWyicRjkfK5eIGRuEqSCG4hbDYtmmzys62ACuJZJgSR6Eu-1D6tO71f8u-xqC63zsAOD4Gv81BLvHtWAMUcoGaLJXTtVUXzdddBfQE4P5ksHeJ0BCtE4uza8z7ISYhxz7n0WQJNI0mmURE8a57WcKjUQ7LHpmoXncLbZNHb9OTEV0DjdthwQ-H0V3NKHTdV_CA-fKQUSf5SYVt8lKQvq_YES9R4eRtrjuRSvlOasowavidsMx5_es2w4Tc4tLa1FPSOXaUESfCjgqABd5I3z9cab8mR8Uve9xo282FQ-8cAOD3Y-6o3MapVjem8wZkj9At3uqYc=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (Here, I encode each $2$-core by its length.)